# Как найти все слова до определённого слова

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Допустим есть строка

```
http://test.com/article/page/5
```

Как подобрать выражение для поиска всего что находится до `/page/5`, при этом `/page/5` может отсутствовать в строке?

```
(.+(?:\/page\/[0-9]+)?)(\/page\/[0-9]+)?
```

https://regex101.com/r/jyz20s/1

И чтобы было две группы:
первая до `/page/[0-9]`
вторая `/page[0-9]` если есть эта часть

Comment: Ваша регулярка будет работать корректно, если включить режим [right-to-left](https://regex101.com/r/H1hROe/1). Напишите [в вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1521438/edit), какой диалект регулярных выражений вы используете или поставьте соответствующую метку языка программирования.

Comment: @Vadik Sirekanyan для php, поправил, по ссылке вроде было указан диалект выражений

Answer (score 3):

Укажите в регулярном выражении начало (`^`) и конец строки (`$`), а первую группу сделайте ленивой: `.+?` вместо `.+`. Тогда должно получиться что-то вроде этого:

```regex
^(.+?)(\/page\/[0-9]+)?$
```

https://regex101.com/r/1wGC6P/1

Answer (score 2):

Можно ещё вот так, чтобы даже если после `/page/x/` что-то было, выражение бы срабатывало.

```regex
(^.*?)(\/page\/\d+.*|$)
```

Работает это так:

- Выражение начинается на всё что угодно, это мы заворачиваем в отдельную группу.
- И заканчивается либо на `/page/любоеЧисло/необязательный/путь`, либо ни на что (то-есть строка завершается).

https://regex101.com/r/kasijR/1

Answer (score 2):

Можно попробовать воспользоваться позитивной группой просмотра вперед:

```
^.*?(?=\/page\/\d+|$)
```

Пример на js(из-за интеграции):

```js
const reg = /^.*?(?=\/page\/\d+|$)/gm
const str = `http://test.com/article/page/5
http://test.com/article/nopage/5`
console.log(str.match(reg));
```